# Hide the top frame on google translate

Tags: html, hide, frame, google-translate

`<frameset rows="36, 95%" border="0">
    <frame src="alfa.html" noresize scrolling="no">
    <frame src="http://translate.google.com/translate?js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=1&eotf=0&u=http://www.apple.com/&sl=en&tl=zh-CN">
</frameset>`

How to hide the google top frame? JS? Jquery? And how...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use iframes with position:absolute and negative margin-top to hide the google top frame. Be carefull with the z-index property.

Answer (score 0):

Know what, this [Cookie Monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908504/jquery-cookie-monitor) idea helped for something weird. I was trying to use Google Translate (http://translate.google.com/translate_tools?hl=en) on a mobile webapp and everytime the language is changed, it kept inserting a bar at the top as the first child of document.body . I am now tracking the 'googtrans' cookie and doing this :

```
listenCookieChange('googtrans', function() {
    $(document.body).css('top','0px');
});
```