# Jquery cookie monitor

Tags: jquery, cookies

What's the best JS or JQuery-specific approach to monitor a cookie through-out the page life on the browser and trigger an event, when the cookie is' changed?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not possible to bind a `change` (or similar) event to a cookie directly. Instead, I would go for this approach:

**Create a poller that compares the cookie value to the previously known value every X milliseconds.**

```
// basic functions from the excellent http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html
function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

/////////////////////////////////
// ACTUAL FUN STUFF BELOW
/////////////////////////////////

var cookieRegistry = [];

function listenCookieChange(cookieName, callback) {
    setInterval(function() {
        if (cookieRegistry[cookieName]) {
            if (readCookie(cookieName) != cookieRegistry[cookieName]) { 
                // update registry so we dont get triggered again
                cookieRegistry[cookieName] = readCookie(cookieName); 
                return callback();
            } 
        } else {
            cookieRegistry[cookieName] = readCookie(cookieName);
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

Usage would then be something like this:

```
listenCookieChange('foo', function() {
    alert('cookie foo has changed!');
});
```

*Note: this has not been tested and is just a quick demo of how I would approach the problem.*

**EDIT: I have tested this now and it works.** [See example :)](http://jsfiddle.net/ArondeParon/5RsTm/4/)

Comment: Note: This is only triggered on cookie change events. I needed to check for **cookie creation** as well and thus modified the code like this: `... if (cookieRegistry[cookieName] || readCookie(cookieName) != null) { ...`

Comment: Hi Aron, thanks for this fine! Really, thanks. It's 2017 and Im facing an issue with eslint rule about `consistent-return` for `listenCookieChange()` where `setInterval` is. Could you update your answer to make eslint happy? Disabling eslint works.

Answer (score 1):

Know what, this helped for something weird. I was trying to use Google Translate (http://translate.google.com/translate_tools?hl=en) on a mobile webapp and everytime the language is changed, it kept inserting a bar at the top as the first child of document.body . I am now tracking the 'googtrans' cookie and doing this

```
listenCookieChange('googtrans', function() {
    $(document.body).css('top','0px');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `jQuery` plugin for `cookies`.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie

It is not difficult to access the cookies in a html document, they live in `document.cookie`.

```
<!-- Add cookie -->
$.cookie('cookieName':'cookieValue');

<!-- get cookie -->
$.cookie('cookieName');

<!-- removecookie -->
$.cookie('cookieName', null);
```

Additionally there are options arguments for add a cookie, e.g. expiry.

However in reply to your question, I don't actually think you can apply a event listener on to cookies unfortunately.

Comment: Your code has bad syntax. You are using html comments in javascript and the colon between `'cookieName'` and `'cookieValue'` in the first example needs to be a comma. That may be the reason for the downvote.