# Dynamic file including in PHP with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, dynamic, single-page-application

I'm trying to build an SPA with PHP that has a static HTML skeleton and displays dynamic content inside a div called main_view, so far I've got it working to the point where the files actually do show the content that I want, but then another problem arose.. No JS executes from the inner files..

For example trying to call alert from the register.php file does nothing, regardless that the file actually shows it's contents in the index.php. Could you point me as to what I'm doing wrong?

This is the index.php section where the content should be displayed:

```
            <main>
                <div id="main_view" class="main_view">

                </div>
            </main>
```

This is the router.js file, which handles the dynamic content:

```
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        const path = window.location.pathname.split("/");
        const file = (path[path.length-1].match(/^.*[^.php]/) || [])[0];
        const isReload = !document.referrer || document.referrer === path;
        //const lastVisited = sessionStorage.getItem("lastVisited");
        //sessionStorage.setItem("lastVisited", window.location.pathname);

        const isRoot = path === "/";

        if (isRoot) {
            loadPage("index", "");
            window.history.pushState("", "", "/");
        }

        console.log(isRoot,document.referrer);

        document.querySelectorAll(".main_nav").forEach((item) => {
            item.addEventListener("click", function() { 
                const folder = item.getAttribute("folder") || "";
                const path   = item.getAttribute("file")   || "";

                if (path === 'index') { 
                    window.location = "/";
                } 

                console.log(folder,path,"das is select");

                loadPage(path,folder);

                if (path === "") {
                    window.history.pushState("", "folder", "/");
                } else {
                    window.history.pushState("", "", path);
                }
                
            });
        });


        if (isReload) {
            console.log("das is reload");
            const menuItems   = document.querySelectorAll(".main_nav");
            const currentItem = Array.from(menuItems).find(item => {
                return item.getAttribute("file") === file;
            });

            if (currentItem) {
                const folder = currentItem.getAttribute("folder") || "";
                const path   = currentItem.getAttribute("file")   || "";

                loadPage(path, folder);
            }
        }


        function loadPage($path, $folder = "") {
            console.log($folder,$path,"das is load");
            const main_view = document.getElementById("main_view");
            const request   = new XMLHttpRequest();

            request.open("GET", $folder + "/" + $path + ".php");
            request.send();
            request.onload = function() {
                if (request.status == 200) {
                    main_view.innerHTML = request.responseText;
                }
            }
        };
    });
```

......................................

Comment: `Could you point me as to what I'm doing wrong`...yes - putting JS in your PHP files, in this type of design. I'm sure you said you were building an SPA? If so then why do you have multiple pages, with HTML/JS content loaded using server-side code? In an SPA all the rendering of HTML should be done on the client side using JS code and templates. Any server-side code should be more like an API, just for sending and receiving data (e.g. using a machine-readable data interchange format such as JSON or XML)

Comment: So your design is a bit muddled, and JS code downloaded from the server and set inside a HTML block just by assigning it won't be parsed or executed (because apart from anything else, executing other arbitrary scripts returned in an external HTTP response is clearly a potential security risk as far as the browser is concerned)

Comment: The general idea was to display different pages inside the same index/skeleton (e.g. change part of the contents instead of all of it and avoid having to reload or re-direct users to new pages for everything) that's why I called it an SPA, it might not be 100% accurate. (this is the first one I'm building)

Comment: Yeah it's not quite the conventional way to do it. You could perhaps get away with loading chunks of ready-rendered HTML from server in this way, but for JS it all really needs to be loaded in via the main page (either inline or in .js files which are referenced by the main page via a `<script src="...` link)

Comment: Adding to the register.php example, what I wanted was to dynamically show info based on the user input using jquery (username too short, already exists etc)

The file it self when loaded as 127.0.0.1/modules/register.php works fine, but when accessed by the index.php via 127.0.0.1/register (i'm using .htaccess and the above mentioned js file to also shorten the url's on the client side), the jquery doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I highly recommend that you learn about [Local File Inclusion attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_inclusion_vulnerability) and reconsider your approach to this. You should _never ever_ allow clients to control file paths!

Comment: `the jquery doesn't work anymore`...is that jQuery code inside `register.php`? If so then it doesn't work for the reason I mentioned earlier. You should hold it elsewhere it load it when your main page loads. Make sure it can listen to events using delegation, so it can bind to elements which aren't added to the DOM until after the main page loads (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements for details)

Comment: The jQuery is inside the register, yes. And I noted what you've said, but the point was how to achieve it running from the file itself instead of moving it. (I know it's possible, because I've seen a website a couple years back that had such behavior, I'm just not sure if I'm going the right way about it..) 

@icecub By client side I meant that the url appears only as the file name for users (e.g. instead of 127.0.0.1/modules/something/login.php it appears as 127.0.0.1/login )

Comment: I think it's a bad design and a bad idea, but have you tried solutions such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74796405/execute-javascript-code-after-ajax-request or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978101/how-to-execute-javascript-inside-a-script-tag-returned-by-an-ajax-response? There are [more suggestions available elsewhere](https://www.google.com/search?q=execute+JS+code+loaded+via+ajax), too

Comment: What you're looking for would be easier to accomplish with jQuery. Basically, you want to use "something", like a word or number for example, on the client side. Submit that to the server side. The server has something like `if($_POST['page'] === 'main'){ return "./pages/main.php; }`. That way the client has no control. If a client changes the word or number, the server simply doesn't do anything with it.

Comment: What I know is that with jQuery you can do `$("#container").load("page.html", function(e){ console.log("This code is executed after the new page is loaded"); })`, which allows you to execute new JS code after the page has been loaded into your page container.

Comment: @icecub that's a standard callback from an AJAX call though, with the code stored in the calling page. OP is talking about causing a JS block which is included inside the newly-loaded content to execute (in your example, the JS would be inside `page.html` along with some other HTML and CSS etc). What you've posted is really no easier with jQuery than with any other AJAX framework, though

Comment: @ADyson Which is, as you already correctly pointed out, a bad design to begin with. There's no need to execute client side code included in newly loaded content if you can have that same client side code just waiting until the correct content is loaded before it executes.

Comment: @icecub I don't disagree with you - I've said as much to the OP (or they can load it up-front, with delegated event handling where needed). But they are asking for it to work their way. I think it's probably a duplicate of one of the links I posted a few minutes ago.

Comment: @ADyson Ye I agree it's probably a duplicate. Though personally I'd never recommend anyone to use `eval()` as one of those answers does, but that's a whole different story, haha.

Comment: @icecub absolutely...whilst it's technically possible, it's generally not a risk worth taking. So my advice to the OP is "don't do it, but it's your project so if you really still want to do it anyway, here's how"

Comment: The difference with `.load()` is that jQuery has its own code that will execute JS in the HTML. Assigning to `.innerHTML` doesnt do this automatically.